# Authorizing a python script to access the GData API without the OAuth2 user flow

Tags: python, gdata, oauth-2.0

I'm writing a small python script that will retrieve a list of my Google Contacts (using the [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)) and will randomly suggest one person for me to contact (good way to automate keeping in touch with friends!)

This is just a standalone script that I plan to schedule on a cron job. The problem is that Google seems to require OAuth2 style authentication, where the user (me) has to approve the access and then the app receives an authorization token I can then use to query the user's (my) contacts.

Since I'm only accessing my own data, is there a way to "pre-authorize" myself? Ideally I'd love to be able to retrieve some authorization token and then I'd run the script and pass that token as an environment variable

```
AUTH_TOKEN=12345 python my_script.py
```

That way it doesn't require user input/interaction to authorize it one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation you're describing invokes the full "three-legged" OAuth handshake, which requires explicit user consent. If you don't need user consent, you can instead utilize "two-legged" OAuth via a [Google service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances), which is tied to an *application*, rather than a *user*. Once you've [granted permission](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts) to your service account to access your contacts, you can use the [`oauth2client`](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) [`ServiceAccountCredentials` class](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/bb2386ea51b330765b7c44461465bdceb0be09b4/oauth2client/service_account.py#L43-L542) to directly access GData without requiring user consent.

Here's the two-legged authentication example from the [Google service account documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts):

```
import json

from httplib2 import Http

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'service-account.json', scopes)

sqladmin = build('sqladmin', 'v1beta3', credentials=credentials)
response = sqladmin.instances().list(project='examinable-example-123').execute()

print response
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Small follow up - the python examples in the Google Contacts API page I linked to seem to use the `gdata` python library (e.g. `import gdata.contacts.client`). The example you provided seems to use the `oauth2client` and `apiclient` libraries. Does the `gdata` library only support the full three-legged auth you described, or is there a way for me to still use a service account / two-legged auth approach with the `gdata` python client library? Just trying to better understand why there seem to be two libraries that both access the same API

Comment: I'm not sure whether the `gdata` library supports both methods, but the `oauth2client` library is created and developed by Google. That said, the `gdata` library documentation [dates to 2007](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib), while the `oauth2client` library seems to be [actively supported](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) as of mid-2016.